# ogr2ogr conversion error - Can't create fields of type Binary on shapefile layers

Tags: gdal, sql, ogr2ogr, geometry-conversion

I'm having trouble using the ogr2ogr tool on the command line. My data is stored in SQL as binary, type is mixed polygons and multipolygons. I am using the following command for conversion from SQL to shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "H:\PolandSQLQuery\test_shp\test3.shp" "ODBC:USERNAME/PW@SERVERNAME" -sql "SELECT TOP 1 ID, GEOMETRY::STGeomFromWKB([polygon].STAsBinary(),4326) FROM [eQUIP75CEEFloodCzechRepublic].[dbo].[CZ_Hist2002_3308238]" -overwrite -nlt POLYGON -a_srs "EPSG:4326"
```

My error message is:

```
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type Binary on shapefile layers.
```

I have tried numerous things, such as STGeomFromText and .ToString() conversion et al. I am using GDAL 1.11.1 (2014/09/24) with the newest MS SQL driver.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean Microsoft SQL Server http://www.gdal.org/drv_mssqlspatial.html? Now  you are making connection through ODBC driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_odbc.html.

Answer (score 2):

I am dealing with the same issue. I would suggest refactoring the file and changing the binary type of the fields to another type.  That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. And actually the problem was as it was written in the title "Can't create fields of type Binary on shapefile". So I just deleted the row "Geometry" type binary. That doesn't affect the geometry of my layer and the export worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error says, you cannot save Binary type on shapefiles.

You need to find the data and select "Use Binary (Blob)" or deselect the field from the options

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I got the exact error trying to convert SQL to a Shapefile but was not trying to convert to binary. My issue was the geometry had several types including Point, MultiPoint and GeometryCollection. My solution was to fix the geometry to be a single type

Comment: The error message states that binary (BLOB) columns are not permitted in shapefiles. This is true (they aren't). There is no indication that different types of geometries are involved (in fact, the `TOP 1` indicates only one row is returned).  The error was more likely an issue of mapping the SQL Server geometry to a geometry that GDAL could convert to the shapefile geometry.

Comment: I found this old post because I had the exact same exception message about binary columns.  My issue was resolved once I realized I was trying to create a shapefile with different geometry types.